# Docker-compose with golang-onbuild fails download behind proxy

Tags: docker, go, proxy, docker-compose, dockerfile

On the machine without proxy, I wrote main.go, Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml like these and `docker-compose up` successfully completed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    redi, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "redis:6379")

/// SNIP ///

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil))
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM golang:onbuild
EXPOSE 5000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
```

However, (of course) they don't run on the machine behind the proxy.
I modified both Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml like;

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM golang:onbuild
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
ENV http_proxy http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
ENV https_proxy http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
EXPOSE 5000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ".:/redis-go-sample"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
      - HTTPS_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
      - http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
      - https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
  redis:
    image: redis
```

And the result is;

```
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM golang:onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY . /go/src/app
 ---> Using cache
Step 1/1 : RUN go-wrapper download
 ---> Running in 8e311bec859c
+ exec go get -v -d
github.com/garyburd/redigo (download)
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/garyburd/redigo /go/src/github.com/garyburd/redigo
Cloning into '/go/src/github.com/garyburd/redigo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/garyburd/redigo/': Could not resolve host: github.com
package github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis: exit status 128
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper download' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As the last error message says, I guess the problem is caused by golang-onbuild or go-wrapper mishandling of proxy env.

How can I work this problem around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment arguments are used when **running** the container and not when building. In your case, building the image is failing. 
You need to use build arguments. The building arguments can be added to the compose file as such:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - HTTP_PROXY: http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
        - HTTPS_PROXY: http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
        - http_proxy: http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
        - https_proxy: http://proxy.mycompany.com:10080
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ".:/redis-go-sample"
    depends_on:
      - redis
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but docker-compose up said "ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here" on "args:" line. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @HirofumiTamori Updated compose file. Apparently, the context needs to be on a separate line

Comment: And also args: values should be changed to "- HTTP_PROXY=http://..." style. But it still does not work. In this time, the error message changed like "Could not resolve proxy.mycompany.com"! May I how come pass the DNS related value to the container?

Comment: @HirofumiTamori how about resolving the proxy ip manually by pinging the proxy and setting the IP in the compose file? In general, I recommend installing a tool to transparently route traffic to proxy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340644/getting-docker-for-mac-proxy-variables-through-terminal/45617554#45617554

Comment: OK, it worked! I'll try redsocks later. But the best solution may be to use exteranet servers for docker development like clouds.